# iOS: Is it possible to override the show-red-delete-button-method when swiping a table view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with the "delete-table-view-cell-with-left-swipe"-feature.

**Situation:** 
I have a table view which content is handled by a background thread. From time to time a pop up windows occurs with the info, that a new element for the table view is available. Hit "yes" to add it, hit "no" to discard it. To delete an element later i use the mentioned "delete-table-view-cell-with-left-swipe"-feature. Everything works fine.

**Problem:** 
One special constellation causes an app crash. When i swipe to the left the red delete-button becomes visible. In that moment the background thread fires the pop up window. I click "yes" to add the element to the table view. The pop up windows disappears and i click on the delete-button. CRASH!

**Crash-Report:**

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44/UITableView.m:1623
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 
'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  
The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) 
must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), 
plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted)
and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

First throw call stack:
(0x1864cc2d8 0x197cf00e4 0x1864cc198 0x187380ed4 0x18b0f2ec8 0x10007fcc4 0x18b10cf10 0x18b2028ec 0x18af41404 0x18af2a4e0 0x18af40da0 0x18aefffc0 0x18af3a898 0x18af39f50 0x18af0d18c 0x18b1ae324 0x18af0b6a0 0x186484240 0x1864834e4 0x186481594 0x1863ad2d4 0x18fbc36fc 0x18af72fac 0x100106cb8 0x19836ea08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**
```

**Reason:**

Obviously the reason for the crash is the inconsistency of the number of rows in the table view. When starting the delete-procedure 1 element is in the list. After clicking the delete-button there should be no more (0) element in the list. Due to the upcoming new element during the delete-procedure there is instead one element left when the delete-procedure ends. I think that causes the app crash.

**Solution:**

In fact the solution of the problem is not that difficult. The easiest way would be to block new upcoming elements while the delete-procedure is in progress.

And that is my question: How can i do this? Is there an easy way to recognize when a table view cell is swiped to the left and the delete-procedure is started? To recognize the delete-button-click is easy of course, but not what i need. I found an other solution which is to implement an own SwipableTableViewCellClass which can handle the swipe. But a much easier solution would be nice.

Something like:

- Override a the method which is called when the cell is swiped to the
  left
- Stop the background thread from firing pop up windows
- Call the normal routine to make the red delete button visible

Has anybody an idea how i can solve my problem? 
Thx in advance!

**EDIT:**

Method to handle delete-button-click looks like this:

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView endUpdates];
     }
}
```

Comment: How does your `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` method look like?

Comment: Please see EDIT-part of my question. But when     tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: is called it is already to late. If i am not wrong this method is called when the delete button is clicked. But i need to block pop up elements in the moment when the delete button becomes visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can implement the following `UITableViewDelegate` methods to detect the start and end.

```
// The willBegin/didEnd methods are called whenever the 'editing' property is
// automatically changed by the table (allowing insert/delete/move). This is 
// done by a swipe activating a single row
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Simply create a flag to mark that the delete is in progress and use it to prevent or reschedule the popup.